# Compare 2 fields <input>, clear the second one

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the first and second fields have the same text despite the font and spaces, then delete the second one text

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input_1 = $(".test_1");
  var input_2 = $(".test_2");
  $(input_2).focusout(function() {
    if (input_1.val() === input_2.val()) {
      $('.test_2').val('');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="dom" class="test_1">
<input value=" Dom" class="test_2">
```

Comment: What's your question? It seems to work as described. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Your question is effectively, 'how can I compare two strings ignoring case and whitespace?'. The duplicates have the answers.

Comment: I apologize for my English, how can I compare two strings ignoring case and whitespace? it's more correct this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want a trim and a lowerCase?

```js
$(function() {
  const $input_1 = $(".test_1");
  const $input_2 = $(".test_2")
  .on("blur",function() {
    const val1 = $input_1.val().trim().toLowerCase(), 
          val2 = $input_2.val().trim().toLowerCase();
    console.log(val1,val2,val1 === val2);
    if (val1 === val2) {
      $input_2.val('');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="dom" class="test_1">
<input value=" Dom" class="test_2">
```